# Why is this line messing the whole output?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-re

I'm trying to do this:

input: "4of Fo1r pe6ople g3ood th5e the2"

output: "Fo1r the2 g3ood 4of th5e pe6ople"

Using this code:

```
test = "4of Fo1r pe6ople g3ood th5e the2"
test = test.split()
x = 0
for i in test:
    x = re.search("[1-9]", i)
    x = int(x.group(0))-1
    test.insert(x, test.pop(test.index(i)))
```

But for some reason the last line in the For loop ruins the outputs of x (which are the new indexes for the elements in the list of strings).

Before the last line (printing x after each iteration):

3

0

5

2

1

After the last line (printing x after each iteration):

3

5

3

3

1

5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the insert method inside a for loop it makes those updates during the iteration, thus changing the values at each index with every call.

If you add `print(test)` at the end of each iteration you should see what I mean. One way to fix this problem is to create a list with the same length as `test` and fill it with each iteration.  For example:

```
test = "4of Fo1r pe6ople g3ood th5e the2"
test = test.split()
x = 0
new_list = [0] * len(test)
for i in test:
    x = re.search("[1-9]", i)
    x = int(x.group(0))-1
    new_list[x] = i
```